# Creating a table with foreign keys shows an error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a table and am getting an error telling me there's something wrong around line 9.  This is the code.

```
CREATE TABLE shirts_link (
    adult VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    kids VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    babies VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    shirt_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    size_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    price_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (shirt_id,size_id,price_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (shirt_id) REFERENCES shirts(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (size_id) REFERENCES shirt_sizes(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (price_id) REFERENCES shirt_prices(id)
    )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

here's the other tables I'm trying to link to..

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    shirt_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    men VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    women VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    boys VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    girls VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    babies VARCHAR(10) NULL,
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE shirt_sizes (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    size_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE shirt_prices (
        id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        price_cat VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        price NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL
    )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''shirt_id') REFERENCES 'shirts'('id'), FOREIGN KEY ('size_id') REFERENCES 'shir' at line 9

Comment: that one is the one I got. Can't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that you are wrapping *table names* and *column names* with single quotes. it shouldn't be or use `backtick` instead

```
FOREIGN KEY (shirt_id) REFERENCES shirts(id),
FOREIGN KEY (size_id) REFERENCES shirt_sizes(id),
FOREIGN KEY (price_id) REFERENCES shirt_prices(id)
```

or

```
FOREIGN KEY (`shirt_id`) REFERENCES `shirts`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES `shirt_sizes`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`price_id`) REFERENCES `shirt_prices`(`id`)
```

but in this case, they are *optional* since non of they are MySQL reserved Keywords.

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

**UPDATE 1**

The data type of the keys must be the same with each other, declare these columns as `UNSIGNED`

```
shirt_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
size_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
price_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb7c6/1)

Comment: both like that and the backticks I get this error.

(Can't create table 'optiq-customtees_zxq_clothing.shirts_link' (errno: 150))

Comment: so it's another error now. when you get `error 150`, it has something to do with the relationship constraints.

Comment: Do `ID` on tables: `shirts`, `shirt_sizes`, `shirt_prices` were all declared as Primary Key or are they indexed?

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq can you show me how the tables: `shirts`, `shirt_sizes`, `shirt_prices` were created?

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE shirts_link (
    adult VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    kids VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    babies VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    shirt_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    size_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    price_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (shirt_id,size_id,price_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (shirt_id) REFERENCES shirts(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (size_id) REFERENCES shirt_sizes(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (price_id) REFERENCES shirt_prices(id)
    )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

it worked for me on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f4f4)
Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE shirts(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
CREATE TABLE shirts_link (
    adult VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    kids VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    babies VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    shirt_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    size_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    price_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (shirt_id,size_id,price_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (shirt_id) REFERENCES shirts(id)
    );
```

Comment: i will not downvote this but this is still wrong. column names aren't suppose to have single quotes around them

Comment: nearly there quotes around Foreign key ('column') too

Comment: yes,my bad i forgot to delete the single quotes, thank you for notifying me.

Comment: I took them off and even tried them with backticks and got an errno:150 message.